# Finding longest name

Tags: java

I am trying to write a static method named longestName that reads names typed by the user and prints the longest name (the name that contains the most characters).

The longest name should be printed with its first letter capitalized and all subsequent letters in lowercase, regardless of the capitalization the user used when typing in the name. If there is a tie for longest between two or more names, use the tied name that was typed earliest. Also print a message saying that there was a tie, as in the right log below. 
In the event some of shorter names tie in length, such as DANE and Erik ; but don't print a message unless the tie is between the longest names.

```
public static void longestName(Scanner console, int n) {

    String name = "";
    String longest= "";
    boolean areTies = false;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter name #" + i + ":");
        name = console.next();
        if(name.length( ) > longest.length( )) {

            longest = name;
            areTies = false;
        }
        if(name.length( ) == longest.length( ) ) {
            areTies = true;

        }
    }
    // now change name to all lower case, then change the first letter
    longest = longest.toLowerCase( );
    longest = Character.toUpperCase (longest.charAt( 0 ) ) + longest.substring(1);

    System.out.println(longest + "'s name is longest");
    if(areTies==true) {
        System.out.println(" (There was a tie! ) " );
    }else{
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

My output is :

```
Enter name #1:roy
Enter name #2:DANE
Enter name #3:Erik
Enter name #4:sTeFaNiE
Enter name #5:LaurA
Stefanie's name is longest
 (There was a tie! )
```

It will just print there was a tie for every invokation.I have no idea why.
Secondly,

```
longest = longest.toLowerCase( );
longest = Character.toUpperCase (longest.charAt( 0 ) ) + longest.substring(1);
```

My friend taught me to use this to retrieve the word but i still dont understand.Is there other way of doing it?It is very complicated for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your logic.  When you find a new longest name (first `if` statement), you set `longest` to be `name`.  Then the second `if` executes.  Because at this point `longest` refers to the same object as `name`, of course their lengths are equal.  To avoid this, just insert an `else`.

```
else if(name.length( ) == longest.length( ) ) {
```

Let's break down how it's changed to first character uppercase, rest lowercase.

```
longest = longest.toLowerCase( );
```

Now `longest` is all lowercased.

```
Character.toUpperCase (longest.charAt( 0 ) )
```

This takes the first character and uppercases it.

```
longest.substring(1);
```

This takes the substring starting at index 1 (the *second* character) through the end of the string, which is concatenated with the uppercased character.

Comment: I am not really familar with how Character works.So from your codes,character,in this case,refers to first letter right?Tried looking for api to understand it better.Is it under Character.UnicodeBlock?

Comment: No, `longest.charAt( 0 )` refers to the first character.  The static method `Character.toUpperCase` takes a `char` and returns the uppercased `char`.  When concatenating, Java is smart enough to turn the uppercased `char` into a `String` before concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Longest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.print("Enter the number of names you wanna enter? ");
        int n = input.nextInt();  // takes number of names 
        longestName(input,n);   // function call
    }
    public static void longestName(Scanner input, int n)
    {
        String name = "";  // First assign name to the empty string
        String longest = "";  // First assign longest to the empty string
        boolean areTies = false;  // Assume there are no ties at first place
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)  // run a loop n times
        {
            System.out.print("Enter name #"+i+":");
            name = input.next();  // takes ith name
            if(name.length() > longest.length())  /*if length of the entered new string is greater than current longest*/
            {
                longest = name;
                areTies = false;  // no tie
            }
            else if(name.length() == longest.length())  /*if both strings are of same length*/
                areTies = true;  // so boolean value of areTies is true
        }
        // now change the name to the lower case and then change only first letter to the upper case
        longest = longest.toLowerCase(); // changes entire string to lowercase
        longest = Character.toUpperCase(longest.charAt(0)) + longest.substring(1);  /* first char to upper and rest remains as it is and concatenate char and remaining string from index 1 to rest*/

        System.out.println(longest + "'s name is longest");
        if(areTies==true) {
            System.out.println(" (There was a tie! ) " );
        }else{
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add commentary or a summary to your answer and how this solves the problem.

Comment: Code never lies but comments sometimes do

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void longestName(Scanner console, int names) {
    String longest = "";
    boolean tie = false;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= names; i++){
        System.out.print("name #" + i + "? ");
        String name = console.nextLine();
        if (name.length() == longest.length()){
            tie = true;
        }
        if (name.length() > longest.length()){
            longest = name;
            tie = false;
        }
    }
    longest = longest.toLowerCase();
    System.out.print(longest.substring(0,1).toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(longest.substring(1) + "'s name is longest");

    if (tie){
       System.out.println("(There was a tie!)");
    }
}
```